# Magento Tax calculation added twice on cart page

Tags: magento

I am suffering with tax calculation. Here i set "**Tax Calculation Method Based On**" is "Unit price" in `System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax`.

So price included tax is display for product on product detail page. So when i add product into cart, product is added with included tax. but on cart page again it adds tax in subtotal.

So tax is added twice at

1. On product details page
2. On cart subtotal

I don't know what wrong with this. please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Check `system -> configuration -> sales -> shipping settings -> origin` in the Magento backend.

Select the right country here in dropdown and flush cache. This should prevent tax from being added twice.

Comment: Hi have four website and each website have one store. i did as you said. but it is not working.

Comment: Tried to flush cache and sessions en try again?

Comment: Hi Gerard it has been solve as the base price is set again when product added into cart. so it calculation is different on product detail page and cart page. anyways thanks for your answers.